# Gnu Make doesn't check header files

Tags: makefile, header, dependencies, gnu-make

I don't understand the dependencies very well

```
TARGET = prog1.exe

SRC = src
# dir. with *.cpp
INC = inc 
# dir. with *.hpp
BIN = bin 
# dir. with *.o, *.out,*.exe

SOURCE = $(wildcard $(SRC)/*.cpp)

OBJECT = $(patsubst %, $(BIN)/%, $(notdir $(SOURCE:.cpp=.o)))

CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -g -I$(INC)

ifneq ($(ARGS),'')
GDBI := --args $(BIN)/$(TARGET) $(ARGS)
else
GDBI := $(BIN)/$(TARGET)
endif

$(BIN)/$(TARGET): $(OBJECT)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^

$(BIN)/%.o: $(SRC)/%.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

.PHONY: help run clean depurate

run: $(BIN)/
    $(BIN)/$(TARGET) ${ARGS}

clean: 
    rm -f $(OBJECT) $(BIN)/$(TARGET)

depurate:
    gdb $(GDBI) 

help:
    @echo "Para ejecutar: \`make run' o \`make ARGS=\"<argumentos>\" run'."
```

Why is Make not checking changes with the headers files .hpp in the directory inc/?

Is right this solution for headers without source files? 
I mean: x.cpp includes x.hpp, and x.hpp includes a.hpp and b.hpp.

```
$(BIN)/%.o: $(SRC)/%.cpp $(INC)/%.hpp
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

Comment: 1. Yes adding the hpp as a dependency of your object files would work, but 2. it will only rebuild a.cpp if a.cpp or a.hpp has been modified, not if b.hpp (included by a.cpp) has been modified. To solve this, use g++ dependency file generation and include them.

Comment: what is that g++ dependency file generation you are talking? Please write me an example or tell me the argument for g++.

Comment: Regarding [automatic dependency generation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Prerequisites).

Comment: You can have a look at [this awesome MadScientist post](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/). And look at your g++ manual to the `-M` options (-MM, -MT, etc). They tell the compiler to create dependency files based on the include list of the file you're building.

Comment: This can't be your real makefile.  Those comments after the `SRC`, `INC`, and `BIN` variable assignments will break everything.  Also, it seems unlikely that `ifneq ($(ARGS),'')` will do what you want.  As for your question, why would make check the header files?  You haven't listed any files for it to check.  To be very clear: make doesn't know anything about C/C++ files: it definitely doesn't try to parse them and understand what header files they depend on etc.  You have to do all that yourself (or, tell make how to do it).

Comment: @MadScientist sorry, I added those comments in the post to clarify and `ifneq ($(ARGS),'')` does exactly what I want, but it may not be the best idea. Thank you for the [post](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/).

Comment: Note that this `ifneq` operation will test to see if the expansion of the `ARGS` variable contains two single quotes, literally `''`.  Make doesn't consider `''` here to be the empty string or interpret it in any way, it's just two characters, like `aa` or `bb`, as far as make is concerned.  Maybe the way you set `ARGS` it will contain these `''`characters always, we can't tell.  But, it's unusual.

Answer (score 0):

Make isn't doing dependency checking on your header files because they're not explicitly listed as a dependency anywhere.

If you want to make your source files depend on *all* of the header files, you can do something like this:

```
HEADERS:=$(wildcard $(INC)/*.hpp)
$(BIN)/%.o: $(SRC)/%.cpp $(HEADERS)
```

That will rebuild *all* of your source files whenever *any* header changes, which works but is probably overkill.  If you only want a source file to depend on those header files it actually uses, you'll want to use the compiler's automatic dependency generation capabilities:

```
CXXFLAGS = -g -I$(INC) -MMD -MF $(<:.cpp=.d)

include $(wildcard $(SRC)/*.d)

$(BIN)/%.o: $(SRC)/%.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

clean: 
    rm -f $(OBJECT) $(BIN)/$(TARGET) $(SRC)/*.d
```

Now, when the compiler compiles a .cpp file, it will create a matching .d file alongside it.  This file is a tiny fragment of a makefile that lists the headers that .cpp file uses.  The next time you build, the `include` line pulls in all of those .d files and uses that information to help calculate dependencies.  The [blog post](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/) mentioned by Tim in the comments has a great detailed explanation of how this works.